# Snakemake tries to run rule, reason: Missing output files, but files are temporary

Tags: snakemake

I have a series of rule leading into using [vsearch](https://github.com/torognes/vsearch), with the barebones shown here:

```
rule vsearch:
    input:
        "{barcode_number}.nanofilt.fastq"
    output:
        sam_output_file = "{barcode_number}.vsearch.txt",
        fasta_input_file = "vsearch/{barcode_number}.vsearch.input.fasta")
    params:
        reference_file = config['alignment_reference_file']
    shell:
        "seqkit fq2fa {input} > {output.fasta_input_file}"

        " && "

        "vsearch "
        "--usearch_global "
        "{output.fasta_input_file} "
        "--id 0 "
        "--quiet "
        "--db {params.reference_file} "
        "--samout {output.sam_output_file}"
```

The rule works as expected, creating temporary files (`barcode##.vsearch.input.fasta`, where `##` are simply numbers), running vsearch on these temp files, and deleting them afterwards. However, when performing a dry run with the workflow and including `--reason`, snakemake gives the following:

`reason: Missing output files: /vsearch/barcode##.vsearch.input.fasta`

This happens for every file (about 80 total).

Have I missed something with the `temp()` flag, or how can I tell snakemake that I don't need these output files, and are only needed to convert from `.fastq` to `.fasta` file types?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move `seqkit fq2fa` to its own rule producing the `temp` file nedded by  `vsearch`. Like (not tested):

```
rule fq2fa:
    input:
        "{barcode_number}.nanofilt.fastq",
    output:
        temp("vsearch/{barcode_number}.vsearch.input.fasta"),
    shell:
        r"""
        seqkit fq2fa {input} > {output}
        """

rule vsearch:
    input:
        "vsearch/{barcode_number}.vsearch.input.fasta",
    output:
        sam_output_file = "{barcode_number}.vsearch.txt",
    params:
        reference_file = config['alignment_reference_file']
    shell:
        r"""
        vsearch \
            --usearch_global \
            {input} \
            --id 0 \
            --quiet \
            --db {params.reference_file} \
            --samout {output.sam_output_file}
        """
```

In my opinion this is cleaner.

If you want to put seqkit and vsearch in the same rule you could do:

```
rule vsearch:
    input:
        "{barcode_number}.nanofilt.fastq"
    output:
        sam_output_file = "{barcode_number}.vsearch.txt",
    params:
        reference_file = config['alignment_reference_file']
    shell:
        "seqkit fq2fa {input} > vsearch/{wildcards.barcode_number}.vsearch.input.fasta"

        "vsearch "
        "--usearch_global "
        "vsearch/{wildcards.barcode_number}.vsearch.input.fasta "
        "--id 0 "
        "--quiet "
        "--db {params.reference_file} "
        "--samout {output.sam_output_file}"

        "rm vsearch/{wildcards.barcode_number}.vsearch.input.fasta"
```

In the way you do it, snakemake reruns vsearch rule because you ask for the fasta file in output so if you delete it via `temp()` or something else, snakemake will rerun the rule again.

Comment: I've implemented the first example you have (thank you for this as well, I also think this looks much neater). However, I'm still getting the same result with the `rule fq2fa`, snakemake complains that it must rerun the rule because output files are missing

Comment: @JoshLoecker Just to double check, you don't have fasta file listed in `rule all`, right?

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy , yes I believe I has listed `rule fq2fa` under `rule all`. Based on your comment, I shouldn't have done this?

Comment: Yes. As you listed fasta file as target, snakemake will run its corresponding rule so as to create them, but will then delete it after its creation due to `temp` tag. Removing it from `rule all` should resolve that issue.

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy Ahh that makes much more sense! Thank you very much